# TimeOut for Websocket Connection In Scala

Tags: scala, websocket, akka-http

I have a websocket connection from client to api service, and then from API service to other Services. 
Now by default the connection timeout(i.e when no message/communication is done on web socket connection) is 1 min and I found settings to increase it , i.e using akka.http.client.idle-timeout = 300s and 
akka.http.server.idle-timeout = 300s .

But in my case these setting works on local, the timeout incresed(i.e while running the services locally on my pc), But not when I deploy the services on EC2 making docker images.

So please can anyone tell me why its behaving like this?

Comment: I don't think your service on EC2 is directly exposed to customer, it might be routed through load balancer/ngnix/or any other router... Its possible these intermediate routers might be closing the connection. Have you checked them?

Comment: hi Chenna Reddy, yes the load balancer we are using is consul and from that the services are redirected. So I think I need to check the setting for consul. Any idea about it.

Comment: You may want to try `akka.http.server.request-timeout` from  http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.9-RC1/scala/http/common/timeouts.html#Request_timeout

Comment: I have already tried that, and its working fine on local.But not when hosting on ec2

Comment: @Piyush_Rana maybe you're missing some kind of keepalive? Does this help https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/19945 ?

Comment: nope, @TNW, I have tried that, I assume that it has something or some setting needed to be tot able tweaked on docker or at console level which I am not able to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

This looks much more like a Docker configuration issue rather than an akka problem. You should debug the configuration of your container in two ways:

1. Log on the EC2 instance and inspect the environment parameter using `docker inspect <containerid>`
2. Forcing Akka to print out the configuration

You can either set the following parameter in your application.conf

```
   akka {
      log-config-on-start = "on"
    }
```

Or explicitly invoke by code

```
myConfig.root().render()
```